# CanCan Permission for specific resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancan, roles

My Problem:
I got three Models :

> User <-> Enrollments <-> Course.

1. An User can be member of many courses
2. A Course has many members.

Thats no problem, but now i want to have specific permissions based on the `Enrollment`.

For example I've got :

1. an User : `userA`
2. two Courses : `courseA` and `courseB`

`userA` is :

- member on `courseA` with role `student`
- and member on `courseB` as `tutor`.

A normal student role should only see the contents of the course, a tutor should have extended privileges (eg. edit data, add data ...)

My results on searching are only that i can assign an User to Course with only ONE Role...

**Is there any possibility to reach my behavior?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `role` is defined on an `Enrollment`, the following should work:

```
can :read, Course, enrollment: { user_id: user.id }
can :manage, Course, enrollment: { user_id: user.id, role: "tutor" }
```

The first rule catches any `Course` which has an `Enrollment` matching the user's `id`, allowing the user to view it. The second catches any `Course` which has an `Enrollment` matching the user's `id`, and with a `role` of `"tutor"`. (You could also specify a role of `"student"` on the first rule, but that's probably unnecessary in this case.)

I haven't tested this, and you may want to change the actual permissions to something other than `:read` and `:manage`, but that should get you on the right track.